# Where can I find detailed information about ground lighting systems exist in aviation?

Tags: airport, airport-lighting

While I'm learning jeppesen charts, I find a list of symbols related to lighting ground facilities, there are a lot of weird abbreviation such as:
Standard ALSF - 1/2, MALSR, SSALR, MALS, SALS, RLLS etc.?
I don't want someone explain all of these to me(because there are a lot of them), but give me source, where I can find them all with depiction and explanation.
Which of these are widely used, and why?

Comment: You'll find a description in [FAA JO 6850.2 Visual Guidance Lighting Systems](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FINAL%20FAA%20Order%206850.2B.pdf), and Code 7700 has created [a summary](http://code7700.com/approach_lighting_system.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you didn't want to just be told what they meant, however in completeness of answering the question here are some abbreviations:

- MALSR: Medium-intensity Approach Lighting System with Runway Alignment Indicator Lights
- MALSF: Medium-intensity Approach Lighting System with Sequenced Flashing lights
- SALS: Short Approach Lighting System
- SSALS: Simplified Short Approach Lighting System
- SSALR: Simplified Short Approach Lighting System with Runway Alignment Indicator Lights
- SSALF: Simplified Short Approach Lighting System with Sequenced Flashing Lights
- ODALS: Omnidirectional Approach Lighting System
- ALSF-1: Approach Lighting System with Sequenced Flashing Lights configuration 1
- ALSF-2: Approach Lighting System with Sequenced Flashing Lights configuration 2
- CALVERT I/ICAO-1 HIALS: ICAO-compliant configuration 1 High Intensity Approach Lighting System
- CALVERT II/ICAO-2 HIALS: ICAO-compliant configuration 2 High Intensity Approach Lighting System
- LDIN: Lead-in lighting
- REIL: Runway End Identification Lights
- RAIL: Runway Alignment Indicator Lights

I found them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approach_lighting_system) on wikipedia which has a nice entry on the subject

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Aeronautical Information Manual" available on the FAA website. Most of this are covered there with text and even system diagrams.