# What does MALSR stands for in an IFR chart?

Tags: airport, airport-lighting

I was going through PPL Jeppesen (I am a student pilot), and I was wondering if you could help me out by telling me the meaning of this. Been looking in different websites and other literature, but I just can’t find an answer.

Thank you very much for your patience and help

Comment: *"I just can’t find an answer."* Did you try Google?  The answer comes right up as soon as you put in **MALSR**

Comment: https://flightlight.com/products/medium-intensity-approach-lighting-system-runway-alignment-indicator-lights-malsr/#:~:text=MALSR%20(Medium%20Intensity%20Approach%20Lighting,the%20centerline%20of%20the%20runway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because No Effort Whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation Stack Exchange (A.S.E.)! Many of the questions you may have as you go through flight training are found with an internet search or searching A.S.E. for similar questions.  However,  if you cannot locate an answer that resolves your question there are many experienced people on this site that will gladly assist you!

Comment: Going to give you a tip for your future flight training. For questions relating to aeronautical publications and general flight stuff, go ask your flight instructor first. Usually your flight instructor will have the answer for you or be able to point you in the right direction to find that answer.

Comment: [Where can I find detailed information about ground lighting systems exist in aviation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36730/3201)

Answer (score 3):

[MALSR](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/techops/navservices/lsg/malsr) stands for **"Medium Intensity Approach Light System with Runway Alignment Indicator Lights (MALSR)."**  It's a specific type of Visual Guidance Lightning System (VGLS) for a runway.  You can read about it by clicking the MALSR link above.

Here is an example of how the MALSR would be shown on a U.S. Instrument Approach Plate:

[image]

---

Here are additional VGLS ([from this source, page 29):](https://www.aopa.org/-/media/Files/AOPA/Home/Advocacy/Advocacy/Advocacy-Briefs/Navigation_Programs_Strategy_2018_Final.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Sometimes called "the rabbit" for the sequenced flashing lights.